# 'ChatForm' object has no attribute 'img'

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying create image form field, but it gives an error and is not creating image form field. maybe I'm doing something wrong. It gets message. With messages I have no troubles.

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return '{filename}'.format(filename=filename)

class Chat(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Chat

class ChatForm(forms.ModelForm):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class' : 'form-control',
        'autofocus' : True
    }))

    img = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = Chat
        fields = ['message', 'img']
```

## views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/authentication/login/')
def index(request):
    forms = ChatForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        chats = Chat.objects.all().order_by('-created_time')
        if request.user.groups.all()[0].name != 'superadmin':
            user = 'user'
        else : user = 'admin'
        context = {
            'chats': chats,
            'forms': forms,
            'user' : user,
        }
        return render(request, 'chat/index.html', context)

    forms = ChatForm(request.POST)
    print(forms.img)
    if forms.is_valid():
        message = forms.save(commit=False)
        message.username = request.user.username
        message.save()
        return redirect('chat:index')
```

It must work, but doesn't create img field.

## template

```
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                {{ forms.message.label }}: 
                {{ forms.message }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ forms.img.label }}: 
                {{ forms.img }}
            </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mt-2">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried the below answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the HTML form, like so:

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Additionally, I'd recommend you to remove empty `action` attribute since Django by default takes current page route.

In short, `"multipart/form-data"` is a value of the enctype attribute of an HTML form that is used when the form data contains binary data, such as file uploads.

Your view also seems a little bit incorrect, so use the following view:

```py
@login_required(login_url='/authentication/login/')
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        forms = ChatForm()
        chats = Chat.objects.all().order_by('-created_time')
        if request.user.groups.all()[0].name != 'superadmin':
            user = 'user'
        else:
            user = 'admin'
            context = {
                'chats': chats,
                'forms': forms,
                'user' : user,
            }
            return render(request, 'chat/index.html', context)

    else: #POST request

        forms = ChatForm(request.POST)
        print(forms.img)
        if forms.is_valid():
            message = forms.save(commit=False)
            message.username = request.user.username
            message.save()
            return redirect('chat:index')
        else:
            return redirect("chat:some_error_page")
```